# I an "if/else" statement, can I make a user inputted variable equal different things?

Tags: python

I need my code to print something certain if a user-inputted integer variable is one of a few certain numbers:

```
a = int(input())
if a == 1, 3, 6, 9:  # <-- This line causes the error
  print("yes")
```

What is in there returns an error, how can I make it work?

Comment: Are the `**` asterisks just you formatting for emphasis, or is that actual code (if so, it'll cause a syntax error).

Comment: No, I just wanted to emphasize what needed to be fixed. Sorry, I can see why that would spark confusion.

Comment: No problem, code examples have to be able to run exactly as copy-pasted. Best practice is to do line-specific highlights via comments (or strings or docstrings)

Comment: Also don't ever say you got "**an** error". Python should give you back a comprehensive and very useful traceback.